# Nextjs: react-dom.development.js?ac89:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
<div onClick={(e) => handleClick()}>Join Us</div>
```

This is handleclick:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(Lang.getLocale())
};
```

And this is my function:

```
class Lang {
    static getLocale() {
        const { locale } = useRouter();
        return locale?.toString()
    }
}

export default Lang
```

But I get this error:

```
react-dom.development.js?ac89:14906 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error describes itself, you can only call hooks in the body of functional components, because hooks are intended to hook into the life cycle of a component. So if you want to build your own Lang helpers using hooks, your Lang should be a hook `useLang`

```js
function useLang(){
 const { locale } = useRouter();

 const getLocale = React.useCallback(() => locale.toString(), [locale]);
 
 const setLocale = React.useCallback(l => { // some logic to update locale}, []);

 return { getLocale, setLocale }
}
```

That's how hooks work, extending hooks is done by wrapping them in other hooks.

Comment: I use your code, but `Lang.getLocale()` not work for me. error: Property 'getLocale' does not exist on type '() => { getLocale: () => string; }'.ts(2339)

Comment: @RezMohsnei Using the above hook you would use it as `const { getLocale } = useLang()` then call `getLocale()` wherever you need it.